# Amazon S3 PHP SDK, Transfer folder, but skip specific files?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using the Amazon PHP SDK to upload a folder on my server to a bucket. This is working great:

```
$skip = ['index.html', '_metadata.txt', '_s3log.txt'];

$meta = [
    'key' => $options->EWRbackup_s3_key,
    'region' => $options->EWRbackup_s3_region,
    'bucket' => $options->EWRbackup_s3_bucket,
    'directory' => 's3://'.$options->EWRbackup_s3_bucket.'/'.$subdir,
];

$client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => $meta['region'],
    'credentials'   => [
        'key'       => $meta['key'],
        'secret'    => $options->EWRbackup_s3_secret,
    ]
]);

$s3log = fopen($subpath.'/_s3log.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($s3log, "-- Connecting to ".$meta['region'].":".$meta['bucket']."...\n");

$manager = new Transfer($client, $subpath, $meta['directory'], [
    'before' => function ($command)
        {
            $filename = basename($command->get('SourceFile'));
            fwrite($this->s3log, "-- Sending file $filename...\n");
        },
]);
$manager->transfer();

fwrite($s3log, "-- Disconnecting from ".$meta['key'].":".$meta['bucket']."...");
fclose($s3log);
```

However, in the folder I am uploading using the `Transfer` method, there are 3 files I want to skip. They are defined in the `$skip` variable on line one. I was wondering if there was a way I could get the `Transfer` to skip these 3 files...

Answer (score 0):

I modified the AWS client in a WordPress plugin I created. The AWS/S3/Transfer.php file is where the uploads are managed, in this case. I modified the `private function upload($filename)` to look for a boolean return value from the before function:

```
private function upload($filename)
{
    $args = $this->s3Args;
    $args['SourceFile'] = $filename;
    $args['Key'] = $this->createS3Key($filename);
    $command = $this->client->getCommand('PutObject', $args);
    if ($this->before) {
        if (false!==call_user_func($this->before, $command)) {
            return $this->client->executeAsync($command);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->client->executeAsync($command);
    }
}
```

This replaces the original lines:

```
    $this->before and call_user_func($this->before, $command);
    return $this->client->executeAsync($command);
```

with

```
    if ($this->before) {
        if (false!==call_user_func($this->before, $command)) {
            return $this->client->executeAsync($command);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->client->executeAsync($command);
    }
```

Then, in your declared `before` function, you can return `false` if you do not want this particular file uploaded.

I was able to do this because I can control when the AWS PHP SDK is updated and can therefore modify the code it contains. I have not found any hooks in the PHP SDK to do this in a better way.